# ajax won't correctly pull post using wp_query

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm a beginner at using Ajax, and I'm trying to load a post using ajax onto a lightbox for a site i'm working on. This idea is when they click on the post in an archive page, it opens a post lightbox rather than going to a new page.

My Code is below:

In Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
function enqueue_scripts() {
    //other scripts
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-postload', 'ajaxpostload', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_postload', 'my_ajax_postload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_postload', 'my_ajax_postload' );

function my_ajax_postload() {

    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $args = array(
        'p' => $postid
    );


    $posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    if( ! $posts->have_posts() ) { 
        ?>
        <div class="image-info">
            <p>There has been an issue loading this image, please try again.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
            $posts->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="image-info">
                <h3>Image Name: </h3>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <h3>Image Description:</h3>
                <div class="description">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightbox-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

    die();
}
```

In Javascript file:

```
(function($) {
    function find_post_ID( element ) {
        var link = $(element).parents('.post-link');
        return $(link).find('.post-id').attr('id').replace('lightbox-',"")
    }
    if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    $(document).on( 'click', '.post-link', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $wp_postid = find_post_ID( event.target );

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxpostload.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_postload',
                postid: $wp_postid,
                query_vars: ajaxpostload.query_vars
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.lightbox .image-info').remove();
                $('.lightbox').append( '<div class="image-info" id="loader"><h3>Loading Image...</h3></div>' );
                $('.lightbox').css( 'display' , 'block');
            },
            success: function( html ) {
                $('.lightbox #loader').remove();
                $('.lightbox').append( html );
            }
        })
    });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

My Issue is whenever I click on a post, the lightbox opens, but shows the no posts error message, am I missing something simple or have I messed up the ajax call?

Comment: I think the action name is not correct. Try change the following _wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_postload_ to _wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_postload_, _wp_ajax_ajax_postload_ to _wp_ajax_my_ajax_postload_ and _action: 'ajax_postload'_ to _action: 'my_ajax_postload'_.

Comment: The ajax action names are correct, one is for not logged in users and one is for not logged in users. see quote from [WPMUDEV](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/)

'Hooks that take on the wp_ajax_[action_name] format are only executed for logged in users. Hooks that take on the wp_ajax_norpiv_[action_name] format are only executed for non-logged in users.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass 'any' argument as a post_type for fetching post as below,

```
 $postid = $_POST['postid'];    
  $args = array(
        'p' => $postid,
        'post_type' => 'any'
    );
```

If without ajax you have try to get post using only 'p' (one argument) that will return no posts. 
So try that and check your result.